# influxdb some data not selected

Tags: influxdb

I process data that arrives on an amazon server, put the data in an influxDB (0.9.5) and visualise on Grafana. Now suddenly data from two measurements is not selected any-more before a certain timestamp (11 July), e.g.

SELECT * FROM cable WHERE time < '2016-07-11 00:00:00'

would return no results.
However, the data is still there: I re-precessed one data-file from 15 May 2016, and now the data from 9 May till 15 May shows again.

This is quite a strange behaviour, would anyone have a clue what is going on here?

Thanks,
Bart

Comment: Could it be that your retention policy is set up so that your data is auto-deleted after a time? https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v0.13/query_language/database_management/#retention-policy-management

Comment: What about the query `SELECT * FROM cable WHERE time < '2016-07-11'`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but no luck.